# RxJS : how to organize subscription betwen nested subscribing calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Within my Angular app i ve the following treatment :

- OnInit on lauching a subscibe from a subject call (SubjectOne)
- when there is a new data coming from SubjectOne ,

  and if some condition is verified ; i reeuse this data to launch a second call whitch is a http call from a service call .

Here is my code

**MyComponent.ts :**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFirstTreatment();
  }

  getFirstTreatment() {
    this.subscriptionOne = this.myService.subjectOne.subscribe((data) => {
      this.myValue = data['myValue'];
      this.getSecondTreatment(data['myValue'])
    })
  }

  getSecondTreatment(thatValue) {
    if(thatValue >= 100){
     this.subscriptionTwo = this.myService.sendToBackend(thatValue).subscribe((response)=>{}
    }
  }
```

**MyService.ts**

```
sendToBackend(thatValue){
    let newValue = someFormatingnMethod(thatValue)
    return this.httpClient.post(url , newValue );
}
```

My Purpose is how may i dynamically close the **subscribtionTwo** so it won't be called n times after each time i got new data from the subject .

**NB :** mySubject can notice some new Data even before the destroy of the compoment

I ve tried to use `switchMap` , but it seems to not work correctly

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are starting with one observable
- That observable stays open after it has emitted a value, so we need to unsubscribe
- You then want to conditionally run a second observable based on the result of the first observable

I would take this approach:

- Set up your first observable as you are currently doing
- Use `takeUntil` to unsubscribe on destroy
- Use `filter` to only continue based on a condition
- Use `switchMap` to run the second observable
- The second observable is an `HttpClient` request, which self-completes, so we don't need to unsubscribe

```js
private destroyed$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  getFirstTreatment();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroyed$.next();
  this.destroyed$.complete();
}

getFirstTreatment() {
  this.myService.subjectOne.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
    tap(data => this.myValue = data['myValue']),    
    filter(data => data['myValue'] >= 100),
    switchMap(data => this.getSecondTreatment(data['myValue']))
  ).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data); // the output of the second observable    
  });
}

getSecondTreatment(myValue): Observable<any> {
  return this.getSecondTreatment(myValue);
}
```

Comment: Why you need `this.destroyed$.complete();` ? 
Is that necessary?

Comment: Very good explanation. Do not forget to do subscribe because of second observable - HttpClient request is cold observable - check [hot vs cold observable](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339)

Comment: At the very least it's good practice to complete your subjects. I assume garbage collection would tidy up an unreferenced subject much like any other object, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: stills to not work since getFirstTreatment callback is still recalled

Comment: @firasKoubaa What do you mean "recalled"? Btw, I realise I made a typo - I forgot to add the arg to `getSecondTreatment`. I've fixed it in the answer.